# How to plot horizontal ray when plotting a line?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am wondering how to draw a horizontal ray (not a horizontal line) when using pinescript for plotting?
For example, the following code draw lines for me

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

price1 = input.price(0, "Price 1", confirm=true)

price2 = price1 * 1.05
price3 = price1 * 0.95

plot(price1, color=color.yellow)
plot(price2, color=color.green)
plot(price3, color=color.red)
```

How can I change it in a way that plot Horizontal Rays instead of Horizontal lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `input.time()` together with `input.price()`. The trick is, they need to have the same `inline` value in order for them to work together.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

price1_val = input.price(0, "Price 1", inline="price", confirm=true)
price1_time = input.time(0, "Time", inline="price", confirm=true)

var ray_drawn = false

if (not ray_drawn)
    line.new(price1_time, price1_val, price1_time + 1, price1_val, color=color.yellow, extend=extend.right, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
    ray_drawn := true

price2 = price1_val * 1.05
price3 = price1_val * 0.95

plot(price2, color=color.green)
plot(price3, color=color.red)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use `input.time`instead of ìnput.price`, so that, from the time you can get the price.
This code will draw a ray from the bar you choose to the end :

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

time1 = input.time(timestamp("31 Dec 2022 00:00 +0000"),"input1", confirm=true)

//get price from timestamp
start_date = time >= time1
first_bar = not start_date[1] and start_date
price1 = ta.valuewhen(first_bar, open, 0)

price2 = price1 * 1.05
price3 = price1 * 0.95

plot(price1, color=color.yellow)
plot(price2, color=color.green)
plot(price3, color=color.red)
```

[image]

Comment: This would draw it from the open price. I believe he wants it to be drawn from whereever he selects.

Comment: This is drawing fron the point you select, I updated my answer with image.

Comment: Yellow line starts from the open price, nah?

Comment: it start from the bar the user select. I don't understand what you mean by 'open price'

Comment: I mean open price of the selected candle. Start price is not adjustable in this example. It could be that this is what the OP wants. Just pointing it out.